# bash: excluding found files located in the subdirs

Tags: bash, find, mv

My script looks for the files of trr extension and then copy it to the target dit, (all_trr)

```
dir=$(pwd)



traj_ext='trr'

# save the data into:
all_trr=${dir}/PCA

# refresh PCA folder
if [ -d "${all_trr}" ]; then
  rm -rf "${all_trr}"
  mkdir "${all_trr}"
else
  mkdir "${all_trr}"
fi

#find trajectories in trr and copy it to $all_trr
find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 -name "*.${traj_ext}" -exec mv {} "$all_trr" \; # -not -path "${all_trr}"
```

the problem that the script find already moved trr filles and gives me warning that we are tried to move the same file

```
mv: '/home/user/Bureau/NMR_Analyse/BAK_MDtest_ultimo/PCA/prod_MD_BAK_360deg_300K.trr' et '/home/user/Bureau/NMR_Analyse/BAK_MDtest_ultimo/PCA/prod_MD_BAK_360deg_300K.trr' identifient le même fichier
```

To fix it I have tried to add

```
-not -path "${all_trr}"
```

but it did not solve the issue !

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like `rsync`? I believe it has an option not to replace existing files.

Comment: It might be better to use a dedicated tool like @Barmar suggested.  However, you're seeing this particular error because `$all_trr` is a subdirectory of `$dir`.  You might want to move the files to a directory outside `$dir` and then move it inside `$dir` once you're done copying the files.

Comment: If you can't pick a specific subdirectory as the starting point for `find` to took for files in then look at the `-prune` option in the `find` man page for how to tell `find` to ignore the `PCA` subdirectory.

Comment: You can try `prune` from the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-do-i-exclude-a-directory-when-using-find

Comment: `-not -path "${all_trr}"` doesn't work because it just excludes the directory, not files in it.  `-not -path "$all_trr/*" ` (before `-exec ...`) should do what you want.

Comment: Okay, gotcha, now it works ! Thank you very much ! Cheers